# How to bring JFrame to the back of the window behind it?

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I want to make a JFrame with the drawn shadow.
[image]
I made a undecorated window and made a background with shadow(grey) and empty part(green),and it can be dragged.

The problem is,when I try to drag the shadow or the empty part,the frame can also be dragged!
I want to bring the window under the window(Another application) that was under it,just like I click on the window.

I tried setBack(),but it just put it under every window,not the back one.

How to click through the window?

Comment: The question is a little unclear, but you might want to look into `JInternalFrame`.

Comment: You could try to extend JFrame and overwrite some Functions like setPosition()...

Comment: I want to click through the window,not the internal frame.

Answer (score 0):

I am unable to understand your question clearly. 
In case want a frame within a frame, then opt for JInternalFrame class.

Comment: In a word,I want to click through some part of the frame.

Comment: I would suggest to use JInternalFrame for frame within frames. You can add these frames in JDesktopPane.